# PHP: Changing links if authenticated

Tags: php, session, authentication

I have a website built upon PHP, and a navigation bar with  items containing the page names. One of them is 'login', and I'd like that to change when a user is authenticated to 'profile'. I'm using a fairly simple login system that uses _SESSION to authenticate. Any input on the best way to achieve this (in newbie terms - I'm new to PHP but not HTML/CSS)?

Zach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you just looking for something like this?

```
<? if($_SESSION['authorized']) { ?>
    <a href='profile.php'>PROFILE</a>
<? } else { ?>
    <a href='profile.php'>LOGIN</a>
<? } ?>
```